# How to tunnel remote desktop through ssh to connect a linux box from windows pc?

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, rdp, xrdp

I want to connect to a Linux box from Windows pc remotely. But I want the session to be encrypted. Since VNC free version and  Windows Remote Desktop (RDP) don't support encryption, I am looking for other options. Although X2go serves my purpose well, I want another free alternative. Can I tunnel Windows Remote Desktop through ssh from Windows pc to connect to a Linux box? If it's possible what's the procedure? I know Windows Remote Desktop Supports SSL/TLS but I don't know how to configure xrdp on linux to allow rdp with SSL/TLS from windows box.
Please, suggest me If there is other alternatives or work-around. I just want to connect to Linux machine from a windows box graphically and securely. And I don't want to enable UPnP on the router.

Comment: You say RDP doesn’t support encryption, then say you know it supports SSL/TLS. Those statements are mutually exclusive. It uses RC4 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974131/how-to-create-ssh-tunnel-using-putty-in-windows then point your VNC/RDP/whatever to the tunnel.

Comment: @Brandon that could be an answer

Comment: @multithr3at3d it is the time-honored solution to the question.  As I have little interest in reputation, feel free to pretty it up and submit it as an answer yourself :-)

Comment: I've just started using anydesk instead of vnc.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in @BrandonXavier's comment, an excellent way to securely connect to a VNC server is through an SSH tunnel, specifically with local port forwarding.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29168936/1974978) details how to do so using PuTTY's graphical interface.

Once done, the port you choose on your local machine will be bound to the VNC/RDP/whatever port on the remote Linux machine, but safely tunneled over SSH. So, you will connect your RDP/VNC/whatever client to `localhost:<local_port>` instead of the remote Linux machine's address.

Answer (score 0):

I use ultravnc with plugin for encryption and it's totally free: http://www.uvnc.com/downloads/encryption-plugins/87-encryption-plugins.html